# Getting XFRM states with BPF

Tags: bpf, ebpf

Does the bpf helper function bpf_skb_get_xfrm_state() suppose to work
for ipsec using transport mode or only for tunnel mode?

Is there any possibility with bpf to create new SA/SP (transport mode)
on the fly when an ESP packet is received but there is no SA/SP
present for the corresponding SPI, provided that all necessary
information for the creation is available in the bpf program?